# how to convert large row-based tables into column-based tables efficently

Tags: database, algorithm, matrix

I have a table with 1M columns and 10M rows. This table is stored row by row in a file. I wanted to convert the table to a column-based table (stored column by column).

The native approach would take 1M passes of the file, and each pass extracts one full column of data.

Or I can first split the row-based table into K small files. For example, if the original storage is

```
A1 B1 ... Z1 A1 B2 ... Z2 ....... An Bn ... Zn
```

I split them into k files after one pass. (Ideally I wanted to split them into 10M files, but I am not sure if I can merge 10M files together w/o opening/closing them to save file handles)

```
A1 B1 ... Z1       A1 B2 ... Z2 ....... Ab Bb ... Zb
Ab+1 Bb+1 ... Zb+1 Ab+2 Bb+2 ... Zb+2 ... A2b B2b ... Z2b
...
A(k-1)b+1 B(k-1)b+1 ... ... Akb Bkb ... Zkb
```

Then after merging them, I will have
    A1Ab+1...A(k-1)b+1B1Bb+1...B(k-1)b+1...ZbZ2bZkb

Then I split them again, and then merge until they are column-storaged. This could take logk(RC) * RC cost if R is row, C is column. Also it has a lot of file reads/writes.

This problem is similar to converting a large row-stored matrix to a column-stored matrix, or converting a row-based database to a column-based database. What is the state-of-art approach to solve the problem today?

Comment: This is not a database operation.  Few if any databases allow tables with millions of columns.  You'll need to do this in some preprocessing step.

Comment: What is a preprocessing step? My data is not stored in a real database, but a plain text file. I posted the question for database since I think when people convert a row-stored database to a column-stored database, they would do similar things.