# Read a file after write and closing it in C

Tags: c, database, file

My code does the following

1. do 100 times of
   open a new file; write 10M data; close it
2. open the 100 files together, read and merge their data into a larger file
3. do steps 1 and 2 many times in a loop

I was wondering if I can keep the 100 open w/o opening and closing them too many times. What I can do is `fopen` them with `w+`. After writing I set position the beginning to read, after read I set position to the beginning to write, and so on.

The questions are:

1. if I read after write w/o closing, do we always read all the written data
2. would this save some overhead? File open and close must have some overhead, but is this overhead large enough to save?

Bases on the comments and discussion I will talk about why I need to do this in my work. It is also related to my other post

[how to convert large row-based tables into column-based tables efficently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158813/how-to-convert-large-row-based-tables-into-column-based-tables-efficently?noredirect=1#comment73392568_43158813)

I have a calculation that generates a stream of results. So far the results are saved in a row-storage table. This table has 1M columns, each column could be 10M long. Actually each column is one attribute the calculation produces. At the calculation runs, I dump and append the intermediate results the table. The intermediate results could be 2 or 3 double values at each column. I wanted to dump it soon because it already consumes >16M memory. And the calculate needs more memoy. This ends up a table like the following

```
 aabbcc...zzaabbcc..zz.........aabb...zz
```

A row of data are stored together. The problem happens when I want to analyze the data column by column. So I have to read 16 bytes then seek to the next row for reading 16 bytes then keep on going. There are too many seeks, it is much slower than if all columns are stored together so I can read them sequentially.

I can make the calculation dump less frequent. But to make the late read more efficent. I may want to have 4K data stored together since I assume each fread gets 4K by default even if I read only 16bytes. But this means I need to buffer 1M*4k = 4G in memory...

So I was thinking if I can merge fragment datas into larger chunks like that the post says

[how to convert large row-based tables into column-based tables efficently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158813/how-to-convert-large-row-based-tables-into-column-based-tables-efficently?noredirect=1#comment73392568_43158813)

So I wanted to use files as offline buffers. I may need 256 files to get a 4K contiguous data after merge if each file contains 1M of 2 doubles. This work can be done as an asynchronous way in terms of the main calculation. But I wanted to ensure the merge overhead is small so when it runs in parallel it can finish before  the main calculation is done. So I came up with this question.

I guess this is very related to how column based  data base is constructed. When people create them, do they have the similar issues? Is there any description of how it works on creation?

Comment: Why not try it?  I suspect that it will make a considerable difference, yes.  You will have to rewind the file pointer, but that's quicker than close/open.

Comment: Yes. Avoiding an unecessary open/close will save some overhead, but the overhead's probably negligible compared to the reads and writes, especially if your data counts in megabytes (IO ops against the filesystem are generally quite slow, and they may block your process from the CPU). Your results may vary depending on your OS. On Linux, completed writes should be immediately visible.

Comment: How much memory does your machine have?  If you've got multiple gigabytes of main memory (2 GiB or more), you should consider reading the 1 GiB of data into memory, processing it (in 10 MiB chunks if that's crucial) and merge before writing once to the output file.  If you're in an embedded environment where this much memory isn't available, then you may need to go via files, but if you don't have, it makes life easier (and quicker).  In general, opening a file is one of the more expensive system calls; there is a lot of work that goes on behind the scenes.  Reducing the number of opens helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `w+` as long as the maximum number of open files on your system allows it; this is usually 255 or 1024, and can be set (e.g. on Unix by `ulimit`).

But I'm not too sure this will be worth the effort.

On the other hand, 100 files of 10M each is one gigabyte; you might want to experiment with a RAM disk. Or with a large file system cache.

I suspect that huger savings might be reaped by analyzing your specific problem structure. Why is it 100 files? Why 10 M? What kind of "merge" are you doing? Are those 100 files always accessed in the same order and with the same frequency? Could some data be kept in RAM and never be written at all?

## Update

So, you have several large buffers like,

```
ABCDEFG...
ABCDEFG...
ABCDEFG...
```

and you want to pivot them so they read

```
AAA...
BBB...
CCC...
```

If you already have the total size (i.e., you know that you are going to write 10 GB of data), you can do this with two files, pre-allocating the file and using `fseek()` to write to the output file. With memory-mapped files, this should be quite efficient. In practice, row Y, column X of 1,000,000 , has been dumped at address 16*X in file `Y.dat`; you need to write it to address 16*(Y*1,000,000 + X) into `largeoutput.dat`.

Actually, you could write the data even during the first calculation. Or you could have two processes communicating via a pipe, one calculating, one writing to both row-column and column-row files, so that you can monitor the performances of each.

Frankly, I think that adding more RAM and/or a fast I/O layer (SSD maybe?) could get you more bang for the same buck. Your time costs too, and the memory will remain available after this one work has been completed.

Comment: I updated my question, and explained why I have the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can keep the 100 files open without doing the opening-closing-opening cycle. Most systems do have a limit on the number of open files though.

**if I read after write w/o closing, do we always read all the written data**

It depends on you. You can do an fseek goto wherever you want in the file and read data from there. It's all the way you and your logic.

**would this save some overhead? File open and close must have some overhead, but is this overhead large enough to save?**

This would definitely save some overhead, like additional unnecessary I/O operations and also in some systems, the content which you write to file is not immediately flushed to physical file, it may be buffered and flushed periodically and or done at the time of fclose.

So, such overheads are saved, but, the real question is what do you achieve by saving such overheads? How does it suit you in the overall picture of your application? This is the call which you must take before deciding on the logic.